# How to return certain rows in pandas based on a calculation across a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to perform an action on a column in my pandas dataframe and I want to get back a list of information from another column of the rows that passed the action in the first place, Its a weird way of explaining it, please take a look at this diagram:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: While there are already a couple of answers to your question, please know that SO isn't a code-writing service. Always include what you've tried first. See more about asking questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know, sorry for not including that, although I admit that I wasnt sure as how to go about it, and i definitely wrong to not include what I had tried (iterating through different columns was basically it), will take note for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
lst = df.loc[df['Speed'] > 10, 'No. Plat'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are after?

```
df.loc[df.Speed>10, 'No. Plate'].tolist()
```